# React Error: "Rendered more hooks than during the previous render"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following component. I used react hooks (useHistory, useState) in my component.

```
export default function ClassTheoryDataTable() {

const dataSource = [
    {
        key: '1',
        date: '18.03.2021',
        subject: 'Revision',
        inst: 'HASHEL',
        edit: 'edit',
        delete: 'delete'
    }
];

    let history = useHistory();
    const [tableData, setTableData] = useState(dataSource);

    const handleRedirect = (data) => {
        history.push("/ClassTheoryDetails");
    };

    const handleDelete = (key) => {
        let dataSource1 = [...tableData];
        dataSource1 = dataSource1.filter((item) => item.key !== key);
        setTableData(dataSource1);
    }

    const columns = [
        {
            title: 'Date',
            dataIndex: 'date',
            key: 'date',
            render: (text, record) => (
                <a onClick={() => handleRedirect(record)} type="text">{text}</a>
            )
        },
        {
            title: 'Subject',
            dataIndex: 'subject',
            key: 'subject',
            editable: true
        },
        {
            title: 'Inst.',
            dataIndex: 'inst',
            key: 'inst',
            editable: true
        },
        {
            title: '',
            dataIndex: 'edit',
            key: 'edit',
            width: '50px',
            render: (text, record) => (
                <Space size="middle">
                    <EditOutlined style={{ color: '#1589FF', fontSize: '15px' }} />
                </Space>
            )
        },
        {
            title: '',
            dataIndex: 'delete',
            key: 'delete',
            width: '50px',
            render: (text, record) => (
                dataSource.length >= 1 ?
                    <Popconfirm title="Sure to delete ?" onConfirm={() => handleDelete(record.key)}>
                        <CloseCircleFilled style={{ color: 'red', fontSize: '15px' }} />
                    </Popconfirm>
                    : null
            )
        }
    ];
    return (
        <>
            <Table columns={columns} dataSource={tableData} pagination={false} bordered />
        </>
    );
}
```

Essentially I want to delete table row by clicking the delete icon  in the last column. But, I'm getting the "Rendered more hooks than during the previous render" error when I load the page. I don't know how to fix it. Can someone help me?

Comment: Usually, this error means that you have a hook used conditionally. In React, all hooks must be present in the top level of the function and always execute, not conditionally. I don't see any problems with your code, though. Do you have a stack trace that leads to a specific line?

Comment: If the stack trace simply leads to this file, I recommend commenting out lines to find the problematic one. My guess would be the `handleDelete` function, or one of its lines.

Comment: Are you sure this is the code with the issue? It seems simple enough and I don't see any early returns, or other overt "Rules of Hooks" violations. Do you have a stacktrace to accompany the error, and a set of reproduction steps so we possibly understand better what the UI was doing up to this point?

Comment: @EldarB. yah. there was 27 stacks. Most of stacks show like this /node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js. 

But there is a stack show this line. => new ClassTheoryDataTable
/components/ClassTheoryDataTable.jsx:65, 

then 65th line is that useState code ( const [tableData, setTableData] = useState(dataSource); )

Comment: @DrewReese Actually I am new to Reactjs. So only I have the basic knowledge. There is several components in my project. I used useHistory hook to route between the components. There is a table with dummy data in this component and I want to delete the table row when I click the delete icon in the table. Without the handleDelete function, the code works fine. So I think the error should be here.

Comment: Think you could create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this issue that we can inspect and debug live? Chances are you'll find the issue when trying to reduce it down to a minimal example. If you've this code hosted in a github repo you can import it into a codesandbox.

Comment: @DrewReese I have not yet hosted my project on Gitub. Now I will try to represent the project in codesandbox and I will let you know when it is finished.

Comment: Sure thing. It's late for me, but just ping (@) me again here in a comment and I'll take a look when I can.

Comment: @DrewReese this the link of running codesandbox demo [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/x4jxo) , there is an expandable table & there are delete icons in the table. I want to delete row by clicking these icons. But there is that error. I commented code lines that belongs to delete function.

Comment: @DhanushkaS.Jayasinghe Thanks. It's late again for me today, but I'm more than happy to take a look in the morning.

Comment: @DrewReese OK. no problem. See you when you can. Thank you for really helping me.

Answer (score 1):

The error is being thrown in the AntD component code, but is only manifesting because of how you've specified your table props.

The issue is in your `ClassTheory` component in the `expandRowRender` you are not instantiating the `ClassTheoryDataTable` subtable correctly.

```
const expandedRowRender = () => {
  const table = new ClassTheoryDataTable();
  return table;
};
```

Here you are invoking the function component directly and returning it, but this isn't how React components are instantiated. In React you describe the UI via JSX and pass this to React and React handles the entire component lifecycle, from instantiation, mounting, rerendering, and unmounting.

This function should return valid JSX.

```
const expandedRowRender = () => {
  return <ClassTheoryDataTable />;
};
```